# How to display the bootstrap alert based on the status code returned from server

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, express, bootstrap-4, mailchimp

I have just started learning express and bootstrap. Please help me in displaying the Bootstrap alert message based on the status code.

so far what I Did :

1. created a form using bootstrap
2. connected the form with mailchimp server

what i need :

1. when i click submit, based on the response  from mailchimp, if status code is 200, then i want to show the bootstrap alert in the client side

Requesting for help and it is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if(responseCode=="200"){
    let a = document.createElement("div");
    a.classList.add("alert")
    a.classList.add("alert-info")
    a.innerText = "Success!"
    document.querySelector("#body").appendChild(a);
}
else if(responseCode=="403"){
    let a = document.createElement("div");
    a.classList.add("alert")
    a.classList.add("alert-danger")
    a.innerText = "unauthorized"
    document.querySelector("#body").appendChild(a);
}
```

instead of selecting body to append you can choose any other element. also you can add various response codes

Comment: Thank you so much Aryan :) . i will try and keep you posted